# Set cell vlookup value based on changing Combobox value

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, vlookup

I have input a `combobox` in an Excel sheet. I want it to work so that the user who does not have access to the `VBA` can select a value from the `dropdown` and then the value in another cell will perform a `vlookup` on this value.

In the first instance I have inserted a box and am trying to set a cell value based on this.

```
Sub InsertComboBox()

#inserts dropdown box on the front page and sets the values as the list of DMA from the pipe_totals sheet
#this should be the most complete list so will not change dependant on asset

Dim arearange As Range
Set arearange = Sheets("pipe_totals").Range("a:a")
lastrowi = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(arearange)

Sheets("front page").Activate
With Range("f5:g5")
Set Combo = ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)

End With

Combo.List() = Sheets("pipe_totals").Range("A2:A" & lastrowi).Value
.Range("k9").Value = Combo.Value 'only works on current combobox value which is 0

End Sub
```

**Is there a way I can set this so the `vlookup` is dynamic depending on the users selection?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, just set the right combo name. It should be ok, provided that your combobox lists values from "Range("A2:A" & lastrowi)" as you mention above.

```
Sub "comboname"_Change()
    Dim list_val As Long

    list_val = Worksheets("front page").Shapes("comboname").ControlFormat.Value
    Range("K9") = Worksheets("pipe_totals").Cells((list_val + 1), 1)
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim z As Shape
        For Each z In Worksheets("front page").Shapes
            Debug.Print z.Name
        Next z
End Sub
```

Comment: @dmitris, what you've suggested here makes sense. Yet when I run it it give the runtime error "index into the specified collection is out of bounds". Any suggestions of something obvious I am missing?

Comment: This happens because you write wrong name for the combobox. And as a result it cannot be found in the collection of shapes. This kind of comboboxes are usually named as "Drop Down 1", with the value of 1, changing depending on the number of shapes you have created in your worksheet.

Comment: If you are not sure about the name, try this test sub above, to find out the names of the existing shapes in your worksheet.

Comment: this worked brilliantly last week but is now failing to attach the list to the combobox, despite the name being correct. Any ideas? `     list_val = Worksheets("front page").Shapes("Drop Down 3").ControlFormat.Value
    Sheets("front page").Range("K9") = Worksheets("pipe_totals").Cells((list_val + 1), 1) `

Comment: what exactly is going wrong? Does it show any error? It does not do what it should and does something else? Or it just does not do anything?

Comment: apologies for that poor explanation. I assign the Macro to the combobox. When I click on the combobox nothing happens - the list is not populated. When I step through the code it does not produce errors but nothing happens either.

Comment: It may be important to note the combobox is a form control rather than an activeX control as I could not insert an activeX combobox. error message ' cannot insert object'

Comment: It's ok, but from the above said, I can't figure out what is goin' wrong. Can you post your current code as an answer below?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113254/set-combobox-dropdown-as-dynamic-range-of-values]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want that everytime the combobox value changes, cell K9 will have the same value also. Is that right? If this the case, then right click on the combobox and select "Assign Macro". Then select "Create". Then inside the sub created, which should look like this:

```
Sub "comboname"_Change()

End Sub
```

You should also paste the final code line.

```
.Range("k9").Value = Combo.Value
```

Doing so, means you want that line of code executed every time the combobox value changes.

Comment: Yes you understood what I was trying to say :). I want to do this in the first instance then if this works I want cell k9 (or another cell) to perform a vlookup on the value in the combobox.

Comment: However I am getting 'object required' error. Do I need to define Combo as some kind of datatype? @dimitris