# set combobox dropdown as dynamic range of values

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Last time I asked about this I got given a solution that worked but I can no longer get that code to run.

before I tried this:

[Set cell vlookup value based on changing Combobox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962157/set-cell-vlookup-value-based-on-changing-combobox-value)

```
Sub DropDown7_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim vlook_val As String
Dim v_table_array As Range
'Dim totals_sheet As Worksheet
Dim col_index As Integer
Dim col_index_1 As Integer
Dim result As Variant
Dim result_1 As Variant

Dim list_val As Long

    list_val = Worksheets("front page").Shapes("Drop Down 7").ControlFormat.Value
    Sheets("front page").Range("K9") = Worksheets("pipe_totals").Cells((list_val + 1), 1)

Call front_page_vlookup(vlook_val, v_table_array, col_index, col_index_1, result, result_1)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am trying to set a combobox drop down list as a row in another sheet which will have varying length. The combobox I am using is called `Drop Down 7`. I set the list as column a in `Sheets("pipe_totals")` and the value selected in the dropdown list populates cell K9, which I then use as a vlookup value for some other operations.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really require to use a shape?  Can't this more easily be done using data validation->list?

Comment: Awesome, I would say data validation is the way to go then, no VBA required at all

Comment: @chancea I just need a list that the user can select an item from which will trigger vlookups based on this value

Comment: @chancea this is part of a larger vba project which produces the list i want to store in the dropdown, can i set a data validation list based on a range generated in vba?

Comment: I am fairly confident it is possible though I do not know your entire project.  If the VBA code outputs a list to a column then all you have to do is have the validation source be that column and it will automatically update.  Then you can have the vlookup reference the cell that is the list.  How to do this is: "Data tab"->"data validation"->"Settings tab"->"Allow"->"List" and set "Source" to the column.

Comment: @chancea that sounds great, apart from the fact the list does not exist until the rest of the vba has run.